# Отсутствует компонент TDBGrid в Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.2

Tags: c++, c++builder, компоненты, embarcadero

Не удаётся найти компонент `TDBGrid` в *Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.2*.

В панели инструментов данный компонент отсутствует.

Для него нужна какая-то специальная библиотека?

Answer (score 3):

Компоненты BDE начиная с RAD Studio XE7 были признаны устаревшими и перестали включаться в состав дистрибутива IDE. Для обеспечения работоспособности старого кода нужно доустановить их отдельно.

Чуть подробнее на [сайте Embarcadero](https://support.embarcadero.com/article/44082).

Answer (score 0):

*У меня есть такой компонент в версии:*
**Embarcadero® C++Builder 10.1 Berlin Version 24.0.25048.9432**
*Установлен также Update*
**Delphi 10.1 Berlin and C++ Builder 10.1 Berlin Update 2**
Возможно скачена урезанная версия
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]